# How to set the navigation bar's back bar button without using UIBarButtonItem.appearance

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have a custom UINavigationController like so:

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        delegate = self
        setupDefaultAppearance()
    }
    
    private func setupDefaultAppearance() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = R.color.textBlack()
        
        let titleAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [ .font: R.font.interMedium(size: 18)! ]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = titleAttributes
        
        // Hide the title in bar button items
        let backButtonAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [ .font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 0.1)!,
                                                                    .foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]

        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(backButtonAttributes, for: .normal)
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(backButtonAttributes, for: .highlighted)
    }
}
```

However, the code to hide the title in bar button items screwed IQKeyboardManager. The `Done` button (or any button on the toolbar) in the keyboard or any picker view is gone now because of this. So, I believe I should not use the UIBarButtonItem.appearance() static func. How do I remove the title of the Navigation Controller's back button without making the bug in the keyboard and picker views?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've asked the same question to the Apple Developer Forums too. And someone did answered it. Basically, all I need to do is just the appearance is it is contained in the navigation bar like so:

```
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(backButtonAttributes, for: .normal)
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(backButtonAttributes, for: .highlighted)
```